# Email verification theory - Looking for general guides

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, verification

This is just a general question on how Email verification can commonly be carried out in a secure way in web apps (I am targeting `nodejs` based frameworks, but I don't want any framework specific code, just the steps). I can't seem to find any general guides on the best practices for email verification, so asking here :)

What I have in mind is the following

1. When a user signs up, create a random token and store it in a DB table along with a field `token_created_at` that tells when the token is created. Then send a verification mail with that token and the user id.
2. When the user clicks on the link, the route get's the `token` and the `id`. We can then lookup the table to verify the `token` for that `id`. If when the route is clicked is already past the `token_created_at` field, we simply say they need to generate a new verification URL. If it matches, the account is verified.

This is what I have in mind ? Is this a right approach for email verification ?

Thanks in advance ! :)

Comment: This seems to be a discussion topic (so I think it's off-topic as "opinion-based") about security rather than a coding problem with a specific piece of code. While I think it's off-topic *here*, there is [security.se], which may - but please check their FAQ - be on-topic for this kind of question.

Comment: It's discussion and (even though I don't have a specific piece of code) related to best coding practices around this feature. I just want to see if the steps I have outlined is considered "correct" from a coding & security standpoint.

Comment: Which is why it's off-topic here on [SO], and why I recommended [security.se]; but please: do check their requirements before posting, if you choose to ask there.

Comment: For those who landed here from google, the same has been discussed here https://security.stackexchange.com/q/197004/75955